# Unicity of periodic solutions on a Lotka-volterra system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, soft-question

I'm reading an article on internet. It states the following:

> Consider the following extension of the celebrated Lotka-Volterra system
>   $$x'= x(ax+by+c), y'= y(dx+ey+ f)$$
>   where all the parameters are real numbers. It appears in most texts books of mathematical
>   ecology. **By uniqueness of solutions it is clear that if it has periodic orbits
>   then they do not intersect the coordinate axes.** By making the change of variables $x → ±x, y → ±y$, if necessary, we can restrict our attention to the first quadrant U
>   and prove that the system has no periodic orbit in it.

I don't see it as clear as the author. I've been trying to figure it out but I can't prove why.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The coordinate axes $\{x=0\}, \{y=0\}$ are orbits. For example, if $y=0$ then the equation for $x$ is $x'=ax^2+c$, and the solutions to this equation cover the full real line (I hope you understand what I mean, I know it is a bit unclear and that's why this is only a comment).

Comment: I didn't realise of that... Thanks Giuseppe, perfectly clear, post it as an answer if you want so I can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a solution touches one of the coordinate axes, say $\{x=0\}$, then it touches one of the orbits of the ODE $\dot{y}=ey^2+fy$. By uniqueness, the given solution must lie entirely within $\{x=0\}$.